# Batch update Apple Keychain passwords using terminal

Tags: terminal, security, keychain

I have 41 webform password items stored in Keychain.  Each item has the same password (since each of them is a different wifi router in our building).

Every few months, I need to update all of these items to reflect the new password set up our sys admin.  Is there a quick terminal script that I can use to batch update the password of any item whose name contains "10.18.124." from "oldpw" to "newpw"?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with [security(1)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html).

The command should like something like this:

```
security add-generic-password -a 10.18.124.1 -w "newpw" -j "Password Updated 2017-05-17 12:04" -U
```

- `-a` Specify account name (required)
- `-w` Specify password to be added
- `-j` Specify comment string (optional)
- `-U` Update item if it already exists

I don't think there is a "contains" feature so you maybe have to loop this.